# why does dynamically created buttons are not being removed on click?

Tags: javascript

In here button is dynamically created and on click it should disappear but only first button disappears on click after it no other button disappears and remains on same place.

What could be reason.

```js
var button;

function createDiv(){
    button = document.createElement('button');
    button.innerHTML = "click"
    document.body.appendChild(button);
    
    button.addEventListener('click', delDiv);
}

function delDiv(){
    button.remove();
}

//two buttons are created

createDiv();
createDiv();
```

Comment: The second created button will be removed as expected, but you are overwriting the global `button` variable. Instead you can declare the button variable with createDiv and pass 'delDiv' when you add the listener to create a closure around each created element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because your function overwrite the last button reference, and can delete only the last one.

you can use your local button reference to do your delete

```js
function createDiv( x ) 
  {
  let button = document.createElement('button')
  button.textContent = "click " + x
  document.body.appendChild(button)
    
  button.addEventListener('click', () =>
    {
    button.remove()
    })
  }

 
// N buttons are created...

createDiv(1)
createDiv(2)
createDiv(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend explicitly targeting the element in the callback as so:

```js
var button;

function createDiv() {
  button = document.createElement('button');
  button.innerHTML = "click"
  document.body.appendChild(button);

  button.addEventListener('click', delDiv);
}

function delDiv(e) {
  e.target.remove();
}

//two buttons are created

createDiv();
createDiv();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are re-writing the button reference as you are assigning a new value again to button.

So, you could re-write your `click` listener function like this.

```js
var button;

function createDiv(){
    button = document.createElement('button');
    button.innerHTML = "click"
    document.body.appendChild(button);
    
    button.addEventListener('click', delDiv);
}

function delDiv(e){
   e.target.remove();
}

//two buttons are created

createDiv();
createDiv();
```

Comment: Thank you very much but what if i have a div and inside button is there but i want remove whole div instead of just button on click.

Comment: I would recommend you to log 'e' in console and explore the DOM functions which javascript provides. For your case, `e.target.parentElement.remove()` would do, as you can access `parentElement` of a selected html element.